# Creating a code review in TFS AFTER checking in the code

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I found this topic for creating code reviews in TFS https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/get-code-reviewed-vs
but this one is "**before**" checking in the code.
I have already checked in the code, so now basically want to create a code review from my last couple change sets. How can I do that? 
I am using `VS2013 Ultimate`

Answer (score 1):

Ok this weblog explains it: You can right click on the change set column in History of your check-ins and request a review from there. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2012/07/13/vs-tfs-2012-tidbits-requesting-a-code-review-on-code-already-checked-in.aspx